# @WebServlet annotation on GenericServlet running on Jetty9

Tags: java, servlets, annotations, jetty

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810306/appointment-scheduling....

Answer (score 1):

It is a requirement of the Servlet specification. See section 8.1.1 of the Servlet 3.1 specification.